# 2 discord bots in 1 heroku application

Tags: python, heroku, discord, bots

i wanna have 2 different discord bot folders in 1 Heroku application, is this possible?
ex: making procfile call a python file from another folder, so i can separate the 2 bots
because i have multiple bots and i don't wanna have a lot of applications, and bc i can have more than 5

i tried doing it but with no success, so plz if anyone knows a method plz tell me.
thank you.

hello, i wanna have 2 different discord bot folders in 1 Heroku application, is this possible?
ex: making procfile call a python file from another folder, so i can separate the 2 bots
because i have multiple bots and i don't wanna have a lot of applications, and bc i can have more than 5

i tried doing it but with no success, so plz if anyone knows a method plz tell me.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your starting script make two variables:

```py
bot1 = Client...
bot2 = Client...
```

Add in the event listener on ready for `bot1`

```py
bot2.login(token2)
```

Now do

```py
bot1.login(token1)
```

It would first login your first bot, and when that is ready, login the second one.